# How hide right scrollbar / rightbar on diff preview

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

My main question is: How to hide this semi transparent scrollbar think on the right side.

Additionally I need help with double number columns on the left.

In conclusion: I want to make my diff preview similar to normal view:
[image]

with addition of red/green sections.

I tried:

```
  "editor.scrollbar.horizontal": "hidden",
  "editor.scrollbar.vertical": "hidden",
  "editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 0,
  "editor.overviewRulerBorder": false,
```

Answer (score 1):

For the transparent sidebar, right click on it and uncheck `Minimap`

[image]

Comment: I have disabled Minimap already.